# Install Zabbix Server on NixOS

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, zabbix, nix, nixos

## What I have

I have a server (raspberry pi connected to a fritzbox-router via ethernet) with a fresh nixos installation on it. I can connect to it via `ssh` (`ssh admin@nixos.fritz.box`).
I already have some experience with nixos, but not much.

## What I want

I would like it to run a **zabbix server** on it and connect have **a web interface** to connect to (for example at `nixos.fritz.box/zabbix`, but I don't really care where).

## What I tried

I found that there are multiple packages for zabbix on `https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs`:

- packages on [pkgs/servers/monitoring/zabbix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/servers/monitoring/zabbix) for zabbix-server, -web, -agent and -proxy.
- modules on [nixos/modules/services/monitoring](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/nixos/modules/services/monitoring) for zabbix-server,-agent and -proxy.

Also `nix search zabbix` gave me hints on `zabbix-cli` and `zabbixctl`, which I belive are there for managing an existing zabbix installation and therefore not helpfull for my problem.

I looked up zabbix in the [options for configuration.nix](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=unstable&from=0&size=30&sort=relevance&query=zabbix) and found a lot.
Most promissing looking was `services.zabbixServer.enable`. I set that to `true` in my config and rebuilt it. This seems to have worked:

```
systemctl status zabbix-server.service

● zabbix-server.service - Zabbix Server
     Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/dxm7imx0ryfxdyqq5bj42klprycnpzna-unit-zabbix-server.service/zabbix-server.service; enab>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-31 17:45:59 UTC; 17h ago
    Process: 14883 ExecStartPre=/nix/store/1py4ma02cnarrnx2yhz1gnjgpv4m9v06-unit-script-zabbix-server-pre-start/bin/zab>
   Main PID: 14896 (zabbix_server)
         IP: 41.4K in, 62.1K out
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 4481)
     Memory: 33.0M
...
```

```
sudo netstat  -nap | grep zabbix
[sudo] password for admin: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14896/zabbix_server
...
```

But I still don't know how to connect to a web interface.

I tried to enable zabbix-web (`services.zabbixWeb.enable` to true) but ran into an error and I don't know how to resolve it:

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: The option `services.zabbixWeb.virtualHost' is used but not defined.
```

I looked through hints on zabbix in the following manuals, but didn't find any hints on zabbix there.:

- [nix-manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/)
- [nixpkgs-manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/)
- [nixos-manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/) (which contains a lot of application-specific help, for example for [nextcloud](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#module-services-nextcloud))

## What I wish for

I would like to have a minimal `configuration.nix` that allows to run zabbix server and connect to its webinterface with a browser.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that `services.zabbixWeb.virtualHost` is used but not defined.  The solution to this is most likely to define a value for that option.  You can find the documentation for `services.zabbixWeb.virtualHost` here:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/be1c62932fc9889f91055f13311cc3789c197565/nixos/modules/services/web-apps/zabbix.nix#L115

In that file you will see many other options are defined, and you will probably  need to set many of them too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David Grayson (whos answer I marked as solving to be fair to him) I figured that this is the minimal setup to log in as `zabbix.localhost` (with the zabbix default credentials).

```yaml
  services.zabbixServer.enable = true;
  services.zabbixWeb = {
    enable = true;
    virtualHost = {
      hostName = "zabbix.localhost";
      adminAddr = "webmaster@localhost";
    };
  };
```

Also nice to add for having a client on the server:

```yaml
  # technically not needed on the server, but good for testing.
  services.zabbixAgent = {
    enable = true;
    server = "localhost";
  };
```